# Send Alt+F4 to hosting application

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, pid

I'm trying to send the key combination <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> from within a `C#-script` to the hosting software. I have not succeeded as you might understand from my question here.

I have an application running a script of mine to do a little file parsing. 
After that file parsing is done I want my script to close the application.

From what I have found, I can see the process ID and kill it. That causes my hosting software to stall and restart. That is not the objective here. The correct way to end the application is to use the key combination <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

But how can I pass that from my script to the hosting application?
I might be able to do it if I send it to the process name. BUT there might more than one instance of this application running simultaneously.

So is it possible to find the hosting applications ID and send <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to only that instance?

And by the way. I have found the input simulator at codeplex but it is not possible to use it at work...

Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: What is the "hosting software" exactly & how is your C# code integrated within it?

Comment: My hosting software is EPLAN, a CAD-tool with integrated Script Engine. I just select what C# script to run and it does. :-)

Comment: The correct was is to send WM_SYSCOMNAND SC_CLOSE to the main window of the process, but first you have to find it.

Comment: Does this other hosting software have an API? If so, there's probably a more elegant `Close` (or similar) method to call against the application instance. Or you could possibly use context manager in your C# code, etc.

Comment: Ideally, the host should provide an interface to the script for terminating. If not, how about sending the Message WM_CLOSE to the main window in the current process?

Comment: Maybe - just maybe - you are not using the right tool. If you managed to write a C# script to be run in EPLAN, I am sure you'll manage to write a Console App in Visual Studio Community Ed. Should suffice for "a little file parsing" and console progs automagically _exit_ when there is not code left to execute :D Or do you need some EPLAN infrastructure for that file parsing? It sounded as if you were just "hijacking" its scripting engine.

Comment: @Nineberry According to the developer of the hosting software there is no direct interface or command to shut down the application. Can you tell me a little bit more about that WM_CLOSE. I dont know anything about it.

Comment: @Fildor As an old DOS-programmer and Basic for that matter also (Thats how old I am. :-) ) I´m using Notepad++ for editing my script and EPLAN has its own motor for executing C# and VB script for advanced automated processing of internal and external tasks. As such my file parsing is an external task and it is the last thing I do before exiting the software. It would be nice to have that exit command sent automatically when the script is ready instead of me waiting somewhere between 10 sec to 20 minutes depending on the size of the task. I think hijacking is fun but here it is allowed. :-)

Comment: How about writing an external program that you call from your script, passing the current process id as a parameter. The external program then waits for a bit to give EPLAN a chance to terminate script execution and then uses `Process.GetProcessById(PassedProcessID).CloseMainWindow()` to close EPLAN.

Comment: @TomasNordström Sounds legit. Just the missing EXIT is of course an inconvenience. But what I was just asking myself: What happens if you start the script and close EPLAN (manually, with the X or File->Quit). Will it be kept open until the script has finished or will the script just be aborted?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when we know that the host application has one main window open, we can send a Close message to the main window of the current process.

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
```

Comment: Not every process has a "main" window. Windows for instance doesn't defines such concept as far as I know, and .NET some times pick one window from the process or sometimes return null as the main window. That's quite unreliable in general.

Comment: @NineBerry - Your suggestion works to kill the process but it looks like Windows sees it like an error and starts to "collect information" and restarts the software. I need a more clean ending. :-(

Comment: @TomasNordström When the application crashes in this case, it seems to me that the software is not prepared for the case that the application terminates while a script is being executed. I would say that any way you try to implement this will result in the same kind of crash. The vendor of the software has to fix that.